# Inherit operators defined outside class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, operator-overloading

In this minimal example I have a class `A` with an operator `+` defined outsise of it:

```
template<class T> class A {};

template<class T1, class T2> void operator+(A<T1> a, A<T2> b) {}

template<class T> class B : public A<T> {};

int main(int, char**) {
    B<int> a, b;
    a + b;
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to create an implicit conversion from `B` to `A` but it requires the `operator+` to be a `friend` of `A` and be defined inside `A` which will cause problems when more than one instance of `A<...>` gets instantiated.

So, is there any other way to do this without having to define the `operator+` again?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What's wrong with writing `void operator+(A const& lhs, A const& rhs)`?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The code doesn't compile, and even if we look at the closest thing that does, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: `template<class T> class B : public A {};` is wrong. Perhaps you meant to use `template<class T> class B : public A<T> {};`. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I'm sorry, that was what I meant. I have operator defined for `A` class but want them to be inherited by `B`. I will edit it now.

Comment: not sure if you are still editing, but `void operator+(A<T1> a, A<T2> b)` doesnt make much sense as an operator that is supposed to add something (no return and passing values). You also cannot really add two `A` with that ;)

Comment: I am sorry for the mess, the code compiles now. In my actual code I have many operators defined for class `A` and would like to use them in a new class `B` (the reason I'm making the class `B` is that I need it to have a specialization for a particular template argument that changes `operator()`).

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class T> class A {
  template<class T2>
  friend void operator+(A const& lhs, A<T2> const& rhs) {}
};

template<class T> class B : public A<T> {};

int main(int, char**) {
  B<int> a, b;
  a + b;
  return 0;
}
```

this works.  The assymetry in `+` (one template,  one not) ensure that multiple `A`s don't conflict with their `+`.

In some situations you really need lhs to be an instance of `B`:

```
template<class T> struct A {
  template<class D, class T2, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<A, D>{}, bool> =true >
  friend void operator+(D const& lhs, A<T2> const& rhs) {
    std::cout << D::name() << "\n";
  }
  static std::string name() { return "A"; }
};

template<class T> struct B : public A<T> {
  static std::string name() { return "B"; }
};

int main(int, char**) {
  B<int> a, b;
  a + b;
  return 0;
}
```

which uses `A`'s `operator+`, but the LHS is of type `B`.  Doing this for `B<T2>` on the right hand side isn't very viable, it gets ridiculous.